# Что делает С# код, и как такое реализовать на java?

Tags: java, c#

```
public virtual BaseMessage ShallowCopy()
{
  return (BaseMessage) this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

В классе наследнике

```
public MarketCommission CommissionRate { get; set; }
public TradingStatistic TradingStatistic { get; set; } = new TradingStatistic();
public RiskInfo RiskInfo { get; set; } = new RiskInfo();


 public override BaseMessage ShallowCopy()
{
   RiskInfo riskInfo = this.RiskInfo?.ShallowCopy() as RiskInfo;
  TradingStatistic tradingStatistic = this.TradingStatistic?.ShallowCopy() as TradingStatistic;
  MarketCommission marketCommission = this.CommissionRate.ShallowCopy();
  AccountInfo accountInfo = (AccountInfo) base.ShallowCopy();
  accountInfo.RiskInfo = riskInfo;
  accountInfo.TradingStatistic = tradingStatistic;
  accountInfo.CommissionRate = marketCommission;
  return (BaseMessage) accountInfo;
}
```

Все классы такие как: `RiskInfo`, `TradingStatistic` и т.д, созданы мною и имеют поля для записи данных.

Comment: Нечего он не делает. Просто создает объект типа `AccountInfo`, заполняет и возвращает его. Нету ни логики, ни чего либо еще...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код почти без проблем скомпилируется в яве.

Единственное необычное здесь это оператор `?`

Запись на сишарпе

```
foo?bar
```

эквивалентна следующему ява коду.

```
foo==null?null:foo.bar
```

Ключевое слово `virtual` нужно выбросить.